# Partial commit of inheritance entity when exists a constraint violation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, rollback

I have mapped three JPA classes, just like this.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "super_table")
public abstract class SuperClass {
  @Id
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child_table_a")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "fk_id_super_table")
public class ChildA extends SuperClass {
  ...
  @Column(name = "serial_code", nullable = true, unique = true)
  public String getSerialCode() {
    return serialCode;
  }
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child_table_b")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "fk_id_super_table")
public class ChildB extends SuperClass {
  ...
}
```

So, there is a method to persist objects. This method is annotated by `@Transactional` annotation. My obvious intention is avoid persist something wrong or incompletely.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void salvar(SuperClass obj) {
    getEntityManager().persist(obj);
}
```

When the object is ok, the method performs right. When the method try to persist an object `ChildA`, if the fields of superclass are ok, but the field `serialCode` has a value existent on table (unique constraint), the annotated method doesn't throws any exception. When Spring framework tries to commit, it throws an exception (about the data base unique constraint). However the tuple of table `super_table` is inserted and committed.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

I'm using:
 - Hibernate 4.0.1.Final
 - Spring 3.2.2
 - JBoss AS 7.1

Comment: Have you enabled transaction management / configured a transaction manager? Sounds a lot like each statement is auto-committed which is what would happen in the absence of a transaction manager. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations for more details on configuring one.

Comment: Thank you by attention, @codemonkey . Actually, I'm using default JTA transaction manager. Is the transaction manager need to be specified by another way?

Comment: Can you share your config for the transaction manager? Have enabled annotation processing for transactions with either `@EnableTransactionManagement` or `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>`?